# setting complex types in java apache web service call

Tags: java, apache, web-services, wsdl, complextype

a have to call a remote web service which contains complex tyles in the wsdl, using java and apache axis.
The solution http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL is not enough for me, because i have to suppoprt ANY type of class, i mean the serialized class is not determined until runtime. I have no problems with simple types, but when complex types are found in the wsdl, i get problems. See the example,

```
private Object getParamData(org.apache.axis.client.Call call, Parameter parameter, String arg, Parameters  parameters) {

QName paramType = org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.Utils.getXSIType(parameter);
TypeEntry type = parameter.getType();

if (type instanceof BaseType && ((BaseType)type).isBaseType()) {
    DeserializerFactory factory = call.getTypeMapping().getDeserializer(paramType);
    Deserializer deserializer = factory.getDeserializerAs(Constants.AXIS_SAX);
    return ((SimpleDeserializer)deserializer).makeValue(arg);
} else {
// What to do for complex types?
// ElementDeserializerFactory defact =  new ElementDeserializerFactory();
// ((Call)iCall).registerTypeMapping(Element.class, paramType, new ElementSerializerFactory, defact);
```

I can create deserializer factory but active deserializers are empty and i con get any value for return.